# Writing different columns of a Pandas DataFrame in one row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I have scraped a website for extracting the shoes and clothes prices , their image ids , image URLs and some other features,I succeeded in writing the dataframe to a csv file but I realized that the dataframe write every feature in different rows while they have to be gathered in one row , i have showed a sample output from my csv file below.
Any suggestions on how to change the code ??

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import urllib.request

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['PostID','Description', 'Kind', 'Price', 'ImageID', 'ImageURL'])

def scraping():
    global h , df 
    with open("/home/user/Documents/file.txt") as f:
        urls = f.readlines()
        urls = ([s.strip('\n') for s in urls ])

    code_list = []

    for url in urls:
        code = url.split('/')[-1]
        code_list.append(code)
        df = df.append({'PostID': code}, ignore_index=True)

        for br in soup.find_all("br"):
            br.replace_with("\n")
        try:
            description = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'ui fluid card post-description'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'content'})
            print(description.text)
            df = df.append({'Description': description.text}, ignore_index=True)            


            item_list = []
            items = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'item__title'})
            for i in items:
                item_list.append(i.text)
            item_list.pop(0)


            value_list=[]     
            values = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'value'})
            for v in values:
                value_list.append(v.text)


            my_dictionary = {}
            for i in range(1,3):
                my_dictionary[item_list[i]] = value_list[i]

            df = df.append({'Kind':my_dictionary['نوع آگهی'] }, ignore_index=True) 
            df = df.append({'Price': my_dictionary['قیمت']}, ignore_index=True)

            imageresult = []
            path = '/home/user/images'
            images = soup.find_all('img')

            for img in images:
                imgID = img.get('src').split('/')[-1]
                df = df.append({'ImageID': imgID}, ignore_index=True) 
                df = df.append({'ImageURL': img.get('src')}, ignore_index=True)                

                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(img.get('src'), os.path.join(my_path, os.path.basename(img.get('src'))))

                    print(imgID + img.get('src'))

                else:
                    break
        except:
            print("your URL is invalid :" + url)


scraping()
df.to_csv('divartest14.csv', index = False , encoding = 'utf-8')  

PostID      Description        Kind          Price          ImageID                     
QXZ5RjZj                    
        adidas shoes            
                     feminine           
                                     100$       
                                           QXZ5RjZj.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

That will continue to happen because when you call append, you're telling it to ignore_index, therefore each series get's put in it's own row.  I'd suggest passing in all of the items you want in one row in one dictionary, ie:

```
df  = df.append({'c1': 1, 'c2': 2, 'c3': 3, ...etc})
```